# Which PNP is broken?

Tags: bjt, pnp

I have a circuit with 2 PNP transistors, probably one of these is broken. One of these tested gives me a diode between Collector(+) and Base(-) while open circuit if I change the polarity of the test. 
The second PNP instead gives me a diode in both direction so I guess this is the broken one, am I right?
And what exactly means "broken"? What happened?
PNP [here](https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/149/BD442-888571.pdf)

Comment: What do you mean by a diode in both directions?  A diode only conducts in one direction.  Do you mean it conducts in both directions?

Comment: You cannot meaningful measure components *in circuit*, unless you are very sure what you're doing. You'd better remove the transistors from the circuit and test them isolated from the circuit.

Comment: Ok I am gonna remove them from the circuit and edit the question, anyway I mean that I am measuring the voltage drop accross the junction and in the first case i read a value only in one direction.

Comment: If you say that "probably one of these is broken" you should know what "broken" means.